# some fields aren't being saved in django-models

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I am inserting new records in a model using a function-based view, but the problem is that some fields aren't being saved.

I get all fields through `request.POST.get(field_name)` and assign them to a variable before saving them to the corresponding field of a model.

views.py

```
import datetime
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


def CreateExam(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        st_exam = exam()
        topic = request.POST.get("topic")
        auth = request.POST.get("author")
        date_now = request.POST.get("date_now")
        st_exam.topic = request.POST.get("topic")
        st_exam.auth = request.POST.get("author")
        st_exam.date = date_now
        st_exam.total_grade = request.POST.get("total_grade")
        st_exam.semester_id = request.POST.get("semester")
        st_exam.exam_id = auth[0:2] + topic[0:2] + date_now
       # st_exam.course = request.POST.get("course")
        y = datetime.now()
        st_exam.semester_id = str(y.year) +'-'+request.POST.get("semester")
        st_exam.save()
        return redirect('/teacher/')
    else:
        return render(request, '500.html', {"error": "Ooops Illegal access"})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class exam(models.Model):
     exam_id = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True)
     date = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True)
     total_grade = models.FloatField(null=True)
     author= models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True)
     topic = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True)
     course = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True)
     semester_id = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True)
```

template.html

```
<form method="post" action="/teacher/create/exam/">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group col-md-8">
    <label for="topic">Topic</label>
    <input type="text" name="topic" class="form-control" id="topic"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-8">
    <label for="grade">Author</label>
    <input type="text" name="author" class="form-control" id="author"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-8">
    <label for="date">Date</label>
    <input type="date" name="date_now" class="form-control" id="date"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-8">
    <label for="grade">Course</label>
    <input type="text" name="course" class="form-control" id="grade"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-8">
    <label for="grade">grade</label>
    <input type="number" name="total_grade" class="form-control" id="grade"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-8">
    <label for="cat">Semester </label>
    <select name="semester"  class="form-control">
      <option value="1"> Semester 1</option>
      <option value="2"> Semester 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit"
    class="btn btn-primary m-t-15 waves-effect">Save
  </button>
</form>
```

I expect all fields to be saved but the author field doesn't get saved

Comment: First of all, you should consider following the python naming conventions, that would make your code easier to read: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Also, I don't see any input named `author` in your html form...

Comment: change `st_exam.auth` to `st_exam.author` in your view.

Comment: You should also read the documentation on forms: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/ . Processing POST data manually is not the correct way to do this.